# 404 Error display when using "add rewrite rule" and "add rewrite tag"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using "add rewrite rule" and "add rewrite tag" to convert the GET parameters to a directory.
I want to display an error or redirect to the error screen when there are requests that exceed the number of parameters.

Example)
`test.jp/model-catalog?category=pc&maker=sony&model=vaio`
Add the following code to function.php
The directory `test.jp/model-catalog/pc/sony/vaio/` is displayed.

code)

```
function model_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%category%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%maker%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%model%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'model_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function model_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^model-catalog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=999&category=$matches[1]&maker=$matches[2]&model=$matches[3]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'model_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I want to display an error in the following cases
`test.jp/model-catalog/pc/sony/vaio/123xx/`

I want to redirect to an error page or display 404 error when an unexpected directory is accessed.

best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, so I hope it helps.
just added one letter to add rewrite rule "$"

`add_rewrite_rule('^model-catalog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','index...`

Then update the permalink in the settings.